# Do I get a memory leak by not closing my JDBC PreparedStatements?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, memory-leaks, prepared-statement

I'm working with java.sql PreparedStatements, and I was wondering about the following:

In [Java is Pass-by-Value, Dammit!](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm), the following is given as an example of Java's Pass-By conventions:

```
public void foo(Dog d) {
    d = new Dog("Fifi"); // creating the "Fifi" dog
}

Dog aDog = new Dog("Max"); // creating the "Max" dog
// at this point, aDog points to the "Max" dog
foo(aDog);
// aDog still points to the "Max" dog
```

In my code, this comes up as the following (semi-Java pseudocode):

```
public void method() {
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try {
    rs = executeStatement(sql-string, pstmt, conn, vars...);
  } catch (....) { /* error-handling */ }
  /// do stuff with the data
  rs.close();
}
```

where `executeStatement` is (something similar to) the following:

```
ResultSet executeStatement(String sql, PreparedStatement pstmt, Connection conn, Object[] vars...) {
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  /// set pstmt variables...
  ResultSet rs = pstmt.execute();
  return rs;
}
```

From what I understand of Java's pass-by conventions, it's useless for me to do anything with pstmt in the main code, as it will still be null even after calling `executeStatement`. However, because closing a `PreparedStatement` also closes the ResultSet, I know that the `PreparedStatement` that is created in `executeStatement` is not closed when I'm processing the ResultSet.

Does this imply that there is a memory leak here? (My understanding of memory leaks and how they can be diagnosed/fixed is spotty at best).  Is there any way I could structure this differently to avoid a leak, but continue having a method that can execute an SQL string and return the ResultSet in an abstract manner?

Comment: In your code above, psmt starts out as null , but if conn.prepareStatemenet(...) returns something not null, then after the method finishes, the global variable psmt will NOT be null. However calling close() on the connection object, the same one you used to create the PreparedStatement and ResultSet will also close those objects, so you should be ok, no JDBC resources remain Garbage Uncollectable...

Comment: Oh, wonderful!  I had forgotten that closing the Connection would release those resources.  Thank you!

Comment: Just to answer the pass-by-value/pass-by-reference question: Yes, your `executeStatement` method's `pstmt` parameter has no function at all in the current form, as its `null` value is overwritten in the first assignment in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a memory leak here. Only issue I find is that you are not closing the resultSet in a finally block. So if an exception is thrown then the `rs.close()` will not get executed.

As Andrei commented, closing the result set will close the underlying statement as well. I am not sure where you close the connection, but that should also happen in a finally block.

Comment: Yep, you should do that. Thank god that Java 7's try with resources will get rid of such boiler plate code.

Comment: @Andrei Bodnarescu - I did not know that. I am yet to get my feet wet in Java 7.

Comment: Oh hey, if you're using Java 7 defenetly try the try with resources it's way cool. There's an example here : http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=24 (last code snippet on the page)

Comment: Unfortunately I am tied to Java 5 (so no try-with-resources for me).  

I am leery of calling rs.close() in a finally block, but that's mostly because then I have a try-catch inside a finally block...seems like bad code to me.

Comment: @BenCole - You should not be _leery_ of closing in a finally block. It is the standard & recommended way to close resources.

Comment: @CoolBeans ah, I didn't realize.  Thanks!

Comment: @CoolBeans "closing the result set will close the underlying statement as well" Is that true? I don't see anything like that from the spec:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close--

Comment: @KoheiNozaki I think it is the other way round, closing the statement should close the result set. However, in cases of certain database servers (Oracle for example), not explicitly closing the result set ends up eating up the number of cursors on the server side. Eventually both statement and result set would be garbage collected. Good practice is to close them separately in a finally block and then set them to null.

Answer (score 3):

First off, memory leaks in the traditional sense, where you have data allocated that cannot be referenced anymore, do not exist in Java, since only what is not referenced, gets collected. However, in this case you're not looking for a memory leak anyway, but a resource leak (which are more of an issue in Java): The memory of the `PreparedStatement` will be collected eventually and it's memory freed, as it is not referenced anymore after execution of your method, however, the resources hold by the statement should be released much earlier, and not only once the garbage collector runs.

What you can do is write a class that contains both the `Statement` and the `ResultSet` as a member and return this class, like so:

```
class ResultSetStatementPair {
  ResultSetStatementPair(ResultSet rs, Statement stmt) {
    this.rs = rs; this.stmt = stmt;
  }

  ResultSet rs;
  Statement stmt;
}

ResultSetStatementPair executeStatement(String sql, Connection conn, Object[] vars...) {
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ResultSet rs = pstmt.execute();
  return new ResultSetStatementPair(rs, pstmt);
}

public void method() {
  Statement pstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try {
    ResultSetStatementPair pair = executeStatement(sql-string, pstmt, conn, vars...);
    rs = pair.rs;
    stmt = pair.stmt;
    // do stuff with the data
  } catch (....) { /* error-handling */ }
  finally { 
    if(rs != null) rs.close();
    if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
  }
}
```

Also observe that I added a finally as well as moved the `do stuff` into the try block.